How to stop Visual Studio from adding IIS Express to launchsettings
So I've removed all entries about it from my launchsettings. Yet when I start my project in Visual Studio I can see the following with git diff
       },                                           
       "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5001",     
       "useSSL": false                              
+    },                                             
+    "IIS Express": {                               
+      "commandName": "IISExpress",                 
+      "launchBrowser": true,                       
+      "environmentVariables": {                    
+        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"    
+      }                                            
+    }                                              
+  },                                               
+  "iisSettings": {                                 
+    "windowsAuthentication": false,                
+    "anonymousAuthentication": true,               
+    "iisExpress": {                                
+      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53839/", 
+      "sslPort": 44389                             
     }                                              
   }                                                
 }                                                  

I can remove it, but it will reappear whenever I restart VS.
It started a couple of weeks ago, seemingly out of the blue (without me updating anything). I am now on the latest version and it's still a problem. Can't find anything about it either. Mostly just how to prevent the launchsettings from being created, not modified

I was unable to reproduce your issue. IIS only went back when the whole launchsettings.json get deleted and it was provided as "default launchersettings.json".please check if dereferencing "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web "is possible for your project.
Also,more detail would be appreciated about your project.

Honestly I wish I could give more information, but I'm not sure what it could be. Latest Windows 10, latest Visual Studio 2022 preview, the project is in .net core 2.0

Oh and it's a (or well two) asp.net apis

I suddenly experience the same issue. This shouldn't be added without notice.

@TimGeerts Thank you! Good to know it's not just me because it's been driving me nuts :v

please check my answer below to manually lock launchsettings.json.

Okay holy shit so I just figured this out!
So when launching multiple projects there's this new setting called "Debug Target" seen here:

The two first in that list is the project itself, and IIS Express. Since it's blank it seems to default to starting IIS Express, and when I remove the entries from my launchsettings I can start it without. But if I set the "Debug Target" to my project, it never adds IIS Express!
I think I never noticed it because I've only really opened that menu like once before "Debug Target" was a thing!

IIS should be required for your project to run.However you can just deny the write permissions on launchsettings.json for Visual Studio.
Update your launchsettings.json for the last time.
Close Visual Studio.
Open security settings (right-click on launchsettings.json in Explorer ->
Properties -> Security)
Click Advanced -> Change Permissions
Select "Authenticated Users" (or other user group under which Visual Studio is running on your machine) from the "Permissions entries" list and click Edit ->
Check Deny for "Create files / write data" permission.
Click OK in all open dialogs and warnings to save changes.
Reopen Visual Studio and see it fail to do it's update.

The only problem here is that it doesn't really solve the issue and is more of a bandaid solution

You may submit an issue on VS developmer community with minimal stable steps to reproduce:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home
